# I don't understand why __except doesn't start

Tags: c++, exception, visual-c++, crash

My code looks like this

```
__try
{
    RaiseException(1, 0, 0, NULL);
}
__except(EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER)
{
    ...
}
```

However, __except does not start and crash occurs as it is

32bit has no problem 64bit has a problem

Next is the contents of dump

```
EXCEPTION_RECORD:  (.exr -1)
ExceptionAddress: 00007ffc6461a308 (KERNELBASE!RaiseException+0x0000000000000068)
   ExceptionCode: 00000001
  ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 0

STACK_TEXT:  
00000000`07936cd0 00000000`c0ba5ee4 : 00000000`179f8470 00007ffc`676a0efc 00000000`179f8470 00000000`00000246 : KERNELBASE!RaiseException+0x68
00000000`07936db0 00000000`179f8470 : 00007ffc`676a0efc 00000000`179f8470 00000000`00000246 00000000`00000000 : 0xc0ba5ee4
00000000`07936db8 00007ffc`676a0efc : 00000000`179f8470 00000000`00000246 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : 0x179f8470
00000000`07936dc0 00000000`c0ba4648 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`079383e1 : ntdll!RtlpRemoveVectoredHandler+0xf4
00000000`07936e00 00000000`00000000 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`079383e1 00000000`00000000 : 0xc0ba4648
```

I don't understand why __except doesn't start

Comment: Note that `__try` and `__except` are not standard C++; they're Microsoft stuff.